# Open Windows form from non UI thread

Tags: c#

How do I properly open a windows form from a non-UI thread?

Comment: `Dispatcher.Invoke(() => //the code you want to run);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var th = new Thread(() =>
{
    var form = new YourForm();  
    form.FormClosing += (s, e) => Application.ExitThread();
    form.Show();
    Application.Run();
});
th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
th.Start();
```

Comment: I've looked thru a LOT of posts and answers on this topic, and this is the most concise solution I've found.  My own problem revolved around a WebBrowser control in a form throwing "ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated", and the answers dealing with that more specific case were terribly confusing.

Answer (score -1):

You make use the ShowDialog() and Show() methods depending on your requirement. See examples by visiting following link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39wcs2dh(v=vs.80).aspx